# How to get an identity matrix into an inverse operation?

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

Thank you for reading my question!

The problems comes from Bayesian Gauss-Markov Theorem. But it's OK if you have no idea about it.

Here is the equation:

\begin{align*}
  C_\epsilon &=C_{\theta\theta}- C_{\theta\theta}H^T(HC_{\theta\theta}H^T+C_{\omega})^{-1}HC_{\theta\theta} \\
    &=(C_{\theta\theta}^{-1}+H^TC_\omega^{-1} H)^{-1}\\
\end{align*}

I can't figure out how this formula above transforms from the first line into the second line.

Here is my idea:
\begin{align*}
  C_\epsilon &= C_{\theta\theta}-C_{\theta\theta}H^T(HC_{\theta\theta}H^T+C_{\omega})^{-1}HC_{\theta\theta} \\
    &= C_{\theta\theta}-[(HC_{\theta\theta})^{-1}(HC_{\theta\theta}H^T+C_{\omega})(C_{\theta\theta}H^T)^{-1}]^{-1}\\
&=C_{\theta\theta}-[C_{\theta\theta}^{-1}+C_{\theta\theta}^{-1}H^{-1}C_{\omega}(H^T)^{-1}C_{\theta\theta}^{-1}]^{-1}\\
\end{align*}

Could you give me some advice for the next step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Written under the simplified form (please note that I have replaced the hermitian transpose $H$ by the ordinary transpose $T$):

$$A-AB^T\left(BAB^T+C\right)^{-1}BA=\left(A^{-1}+B^TC^{-1}B\right)^{-1}$$

appears as a version of the more general [Woodbury identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity)

$$A^{-1}-A^{-1}U\left(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U\right)^{-1}VA^{-1}=\left(A+UCV\right)^{-1}$$

Comment: See this interesting [document](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/g.ridgway/mil/mil.pdf)

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I have never seen such an equation before.